# Publishing to crossbar.io from python daemon

Tags: python, websocket, wamp-protocol, crossbar

I would like to use crossbar.io to display real-time stats on the web about a long-running python daemon. The displaying part works fine using AutobahnJS, but I struggle with the part that posts stats to crossbar.io. All the example code I read runs on twisted or asyncio, and my daemon doesn't (and won't). For pure WebSockets, there's the [websocket_client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client) package which does exactly what I would like to do, just not on WAMP. Is there a similar library, or am I missing something in the docs?

I'm using crossbar.io over pure WebSockets because I like the PubSub abstraction. I know I can re-implement it in WebSockets without a lot of additional work, but that's something I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a similar question, the solution is to use crossbar's [HTTP Publisher service](http://crossbar.io/docs/HTTP-Bridge-Services-Publisher/). There's also the [crossbarconnect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crossbarconnect) package which conveniently wraps all the necessary HTTP action. Sweet and short :-)